# How to index more than one entity in ApacheSolr

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, solr4

The `mwikipage` alone is indexed by solr, All other mapped entities are not indexed / ignored by `ApacheSolr` while doing indexing,

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource batchSize="1" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="123" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cwiki" user="root"/>
<document name="mediawiki-doc">
    <!-- mwiki page  -->
    <entity name="mwikipage" query="SELECT * FROM mwikipage">
        <field column="page_id" name="id"/>
        <field column="page_title" name="page_title"/>
        <field column="page_latest" name="page_latest"/>
        <field column="page_counter" name="page_counter"/>
        <!-- mwiki page links  -->
        <entity name="mwikipagelinks"
            deltaQuery="SELECT pl_from FROM mwikipagelinks WHERE last_modified &gt;'${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
            parentDeltaQuery="SELECT page_id FROM mwikipage WHERE page_id = '${mwikipagelinks.pl_from}'"
            query="SELECT * FROM mwikipagelinks WHERE pl_from = '${ mwikipage.page_id }'">
            <field column="pl_namespace" name="pl_namespace"/>
            <field column="pl_title" name="pl_title"/>
        </entity>
        <!-- mwiki page redirects  -->
        <entity name="mwikiredirect" query="SELECT * FROM mwikiredirect WHERE rd_from = '${ mwikipage.page_id }'">
            <field column="rd_namespace" name="rd_namespace"/>
            <field column="rd_title" name="rd_title"/>
            <field column="rd_title" name="rd_title"/>
        </entity>
        <!-- mwiki page revisions  -->
        <entity name="mwikirevision" query="SELECT * FROM mwikirevision WHERE rev_id = '${ mwikipage.page_latest }'">
            <field column="rev_id" name="rev_id"/>
            <field column="rev_page" name="rev_page"/>
            <field column="rev_text_id" name="rev_text_id"/>
            <!-- mwiki page texts  -->
            <entity name="mwikitext" query="select * from mwikitext WHERE old_id = '${ mwikirevision.rev_text_id }'">
                <field column="old_id" name="old_id"/>
                <field column="old_text" name="old_text"/>
                <field column="old_flags" name="old_flags"/>
            </entity>
        </entity>
        <!-- mwiki category links  -->
        <entity name="mwikicategorylinks" query="SELECT * FROM mwikicategorylinks WHERE cl_from = '${ mwikipage.page_id }'">
            <field column="cl_from" name="cl_from"/>
            <field column="cl_to" name="cl_to"/>
        </entity>
        <!-- mwiki external links  -->
        <entity name="mwikiexternallinks" query="SELECT * FROM mwikiexternallinks where el_from = '${  mwikipage.page_id }'">
            <field column="el_from" name="el_from"/>
            <field column="el_to" name="el_to"/>
            <field column="el_index" name="el_index"/>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

**shcema.xml**

```
<!-- Cwiki fields -->
<!-- MWIKI PAGE -->
<!-- <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="true" multiValued="false"/> -->
<field name="page_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="page_latest" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="page_counter" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI PAGELINKS -->
<field name="pl_namespace" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="pl_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI REDIRECT -->
<field name="rd_namespace" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="rd_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI REVISION -->
<field name="rev_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="rev_page" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="rev_text_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI TEXT-->
<field name="old_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="old_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="old_flags" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI  CATEGORY LINKS -->
<field name="cl_from" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="cl_to" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- MWIKI  CATEGORY LINKS -->
<field name="el_from" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="el_to" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="el_index" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

**document uniqueness enforcer**

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

**Result**

```
 Last Update: 13:24:39 Indexing completed. 
 Added/Updated: 530 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 1s)
 Requests: 2,651 (2,651/s), Fetched: 530 (530/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 530 (530/s)
```

And when queried only `mwikipage` entities are indexed, And the query result is as follows,

```
 "docs": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "page_title": [
      "Main_Page"
    ],
    "page_latest": [
      "1247"
    ],
    "page_counter": [
      "5223"
    ],
    "_version_": 1492251847862255600
  }
```

Other entities are ignored. How to index / document outline ?

Thanks and Regards,
Bachan

Comment: Have you looked into CirrusSearch's schema? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make ${ mwikipage.page_id } to ${mwikipage.page_id}
i.e. remove spaces in braces.